# How to parse an XML file using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I'm getting an XML response from a CSS validation service that looks like this:

```
{vextwarning=false, output=soap12, lang=en, warning=2, medium=all, profile=css3}
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="utf-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <env:Body>
        <m:cssvalidationresponse
            env:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-encoding"
            xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/2005/07/css-validator">
            <m:uri>file:tmp.css</m:uri>
            <m:checkedby>http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/</m:checkedby>
            <m:csslevel>css3</m:csslevel>
            <m:date>2014-01-28T09:33:32Z</m:date>
            <m:validity>false</m:validity>
            <m:result>
                <m:errors xml:lang="en">
                    <m:errorcount>1</m:errorcount>
                <m:errorlist>
                    <m:uri>file:tmp.css</m:uri>
                        <m:error>
                            <m:line>1</m:line>
                            <m:errortype>parse-error</m:errortype>
                            <m:context> asdf321 </m:context>
                            <m:errorsubtype>
                                exp
                            </m:errorsubtype>
                            <m:skippedstring>
                                123
                            </m:skippedstring>
                            <m:message>
                                Property bla doesn&#39;t exist : 
                            </m:message>
                        </m:error>
                    </m:errorlist>
                </m:errors>
                <m:warnings xml:lang="en">
                    <m:warningcount>0</m:warningcount>
                </m:warnings>
            </m:result>
        </m:cssvalidationresponse>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

I want to parse it using Nokogiri, but I'm completely stuck. I know how to parse CSS and stuff using Nokogiri, but XML like this is pretty new to me.

For example, I want to get the value of `m:validity`, or I want to iterate over the `m:errors`. Please give me some small hints on how to do this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Check out the [Savon Ruby SOAP library](http://savonrb.com/); it will probably simplify a lot of things for you, including abstracting the XML parsing.

Comment: You should probably start here: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're processing a SOAP message, so I'd recommend using a SOAP library for Ruby such as [Savon](http://savonrb.com/).

However, if you're getting the XML document from another source then you could parse it using namespaced XPath queries like so:

```ruby
class CssValidationResponse
  attr_reader :valid, :errors
  def initialize(xml)
    doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
    xmlns = { 'm' => 'http://www.w3.org/2005/07/css-validator' }
    @valid  = (doc.xpath('//m:validity', xmlns).text == 'true')
    @errors = doc.xpath('//m:error/m:message', xmlns).map { |n| n.text.strip }
  end
end

xml = read_my_xml_file
validator = CssValidationResponse.new(xml)
validator.valid  # => false
validator.errors # => ["Property bla doesn't exist :"]
```